# Autofill django fields when entering user ID

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have been searching for solution to auto fill all the fields in my execution profile page, 2

I have a ModelForm with seven fields: execution_number, matter, client, opponent, date, court, update.(date is set to auto_now and so does not appear in the form)

Basically all I want is when I enter execution_number it should automatically fill in all other fields that will inherent from the database.

Would appreciate the help, i am still a beginner in programming, so would appreciate the support :)

## Models

```
from django.db import models


class Execution(models.Model):

    COURT = (
            ('Muscat', 'Muscat'),
            ('Seeb', 'Seeb'),
            )
    execution_number= models.CharField(max_length =200, null= True)
    matter=models.CharField(max_length =200, null= True)
    client = models.CharField(max_length =200, null= True)
    opponent =models.CharField(max_length =200, null= True)
    date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null= True)
    court= models.CharField(max_length =200, null= True, choices = COURT )
    update = models.CharField(max_length =200)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.execution_number
```

## Views

```
def search_execution(request):
    execution_number = request.execution_number
    # form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES) <-- remove

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Execution(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=execution_number)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()  # <-- you can just save the form, it will save the profile
            # user.save()  <-- this doesn't help you, it doesn't save the profile and since user isn't changed you don't need to save it!
            return redirect('/search_execution')
        # else:
        #    form = ProfileUpdateForm()  <-- don't clear the form!

    else:  # GET
        form = Execution(instance=execution_number)

    context = {
        'form' : form
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/search_execution.html', context)
```

## Form

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Execution


class ExecutionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Execution
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the correct approach, but in this case I would use the Django Rest Framework to create an API endpoint that returns a list of Execution objects, and then use javascript directly on the page to download said list and check against it on the `onInput()` event. If there is a match then you can easily populate all the fields in the form.

Understand that the code of a Django view is executed on the server and so it has no access to the rendered page that the user interacts with.

Any sort of auto-completing action has to originate in the user's browser, via javascript. With javascript you can asynchronously access information via API calls and so check if the information being entered matches any Execution id present in your database.

Comment: Awsome thanks! , I am still learning in django, and found what I was looking for in django rest framework, thank you! 